# Periodic boundary condition in Matlab for random spheres in a cube model

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have random non-overlapping spheres (stationary) in a cube. I am trying to implement periodic boundary condition on the walls, so that if there are any half sphere on the edge it appears on the other side. This seems to be a well studied problem, but am not sure how should i implement it on spheres.
At the start of the code, i would have random sphere position (c, r), where c = [ x y z] inside  or on the edges of cube of dimension (dims), where dims = [ l b h ].

Code for selecting  a random sphere in a cube:

```
   function [ c, r ] = randomSphere_1( dims )
   % creating one sphere at random inside [0..dims(1)]x[0..dims(2)]x...
   % radius and center coordinates are sampled from a uniform distribution 
   % over the relevant domain.
   %
   % output: c - center of sphere (vector cx, cy,... )
   %         r - radius of sphere (scalar)
   r = 0.15 + ( 0.55 - 0.15) .* rand(1);% radius varies between 0.15mm - 0.55mm
   c = bsxfun (@times,(dims) , rand(1,3)) + r; % to make sure sphere is placed inside or on the edge of the cube
   % periodic condition
   *if*
```

I am trying to build a  code if the center co-ordinates fall on the edge or over them then there should be periodicity in spheres that is the the other half should be on the other side. I have added an image just to give an idea about what i mean by periodic boundary condition. So the spheres on the edges are exactly how i want. How should i proceed with the problem?

[image]

Comment: How do you want to represent the partial spheres?  Right now, your data format assumes a simple sphere model.  Figuring out the center of the periodic sphere seems straightforward.  Intersecting it with the box to create a partial sphere is more difficult.  Again, depending the form of the results.

Comment: @Peter The other part of the partial spheres should appear on the opposite edges. I have updated my question, added a code just to put things in perspective.

Comment: You currently have no way to represent a partial sphere.  Your output is `(c, r)`.  Do you want another full sphere at `(c + T, r)`, where T is the periodicity?  Do you instead want a set of points on the surface of each sphere?  A set of points inside each sphere?  A surface (triangulated mesh) for each sphere?

Comment: @peter I want full sphere on the edges with the only criteria that the other half appears on the opposite edge. So it would like partial sphere on both the sides.

Comment: You're ignoring my question.  How do you represent a partial sphere?  Please give an example of the actual numeric output you have in mind for two spheres, split across the two edges.  For example, pretend the box is 1x1x1, and you have a sphere centered at (0, 0.5, 0.5).  Half the sphere is inside the box.  The other half should be centered at (1, 0.5, 0.5).  Is that the output you want?  `c = [0 0.5 0.5; 1 0.5 0.5]`?  Or something else?

Comment: @Peter Sorry about that. I have attached an image that i precisely describes what am trying to implement. So the spheres which fall on the edges gets completed on the other edge. The radius remains the same, center changes that is (x, y, z). I am failing to describe them properly.